# (How) Can I configure a fallback for DDClient?

Tags: dns, ip, dynamic-dns, dyndns

I [want to use the Fritzbox update feature of DDClient](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-ddclient#get-dynamic-ip-from-fritzbox), but also want to have a fallback to a public web server, if that does not work for some reason (e.g. cause someone just switched to another router or whatever…).

As far as I known, just duplicating the `use=cmd` key seems to override the previous configuration?

```
protocol=dyndns2
use=cmd, cmd='curl https://checkipv4.dedyn.io/'
use=cmd, cmd=/etc/ddclient/get-ip-from-fritzbox
#use=if, if=eth0
ssl=yes

server=update.dedyn.io
login=domain.dedyn.io
password='___password_here____'
domain.dedyn.io
```

The syntax `use=cmd, cmd='curl https://checkipv4.dedyn.io/', cmd=/etc/ddclient/get-ip-from-fritzbox` also works, but I guess it does the same, or does not it?

In any case [the official documentation](https://ddclient.net/usage.html) is of little help and does not explain the configuration format in a very elaborate way.

So can you actually specify a fallback in ddclient? If so, how?

Comment: If both are commands, why not just put them both in a script with suitable logic and use that instead?

Comment: That is a clever idea! Feel free to submit this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since both of these are external commands, you could create a script file with suitable logic, say something like:

```bsh
#! /bin/sh
curl -fs https://checkipv4.dedyn.io/ ||
    /etc/ddclient/get-ip-from-fritzbox
# Or the other way around, depending on what you need
```

And use that as the `cmd`.